# Using Symfony Form component standalone with security-csrf - error on submission

Tags: forms, symfony, csrf

I have a question regarding `symfony/form` using as a standalone component and `security-csrf` running with PHP build-in server. I hardly remember having such issue with the Symfony framework.

When setting `symfony/form` as a standalone component I tried this code for both v4.2 and v5.1 https://github.com/xmgcoyi/standalone-forms/tree/4.2+twig. A rewrite of webmozart's example mentioned here https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html

The csrf token is generated with twig-bridge, but when submitting the form - on calling`$form->isValid()` - `invalid csrf` error appears.

By default csrf protection is enabled, setting to `false` - the form submits.

Tried CSRF component with both setups with `NativeSessionTokenStorage` and `SessionTokenStorage + Session of HttpFoundation`.

Could you give any hint on what I'm doing wrong and where to look at?

**P.S.**
Code samples with csrf error on submission:

- https://github.com/xmgcoyi/standalone-forms/tree/4.2+twig
- https://github.com/liorchamla/pratique-symfony-form/tree/06-protection-csrf

**UPD**
The apps above work well, the problem was in browser storage filled with garbage.

Setting to `false` in `$formFactory->createBuilder(FormType::class, null, ['csrf_protection' => false])` submits the form

Comment: There are several items that must be wired properly to use CSRF.  Not enough info in your question to guess where the problem might be.  Consider creating a new absolute minimalist project with just one simple form following the example in the docs.  Good chance you will discover what was going wrong.  If not then check the project into github and post a link.

Comment: @Cerad I'm actually using this code - the same error https://github.com/xmgcoyi/standalone-forms/tree/4.2+twig the execution does not go to the var_dump line https://github.com/xmgcoyi/standalone-forms/blob/4.2%2Btwig/web/index.php#L43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess but the 4.2 linked repo has:

```
$csrfManager = new CsrfTokenManager($csrfGenerator, $csrfStorage);
$csrfTokenManager = new CsrfTokenManager();
```

Two token managers.  One is used in the twig form engine and one is used in the form factory extension.  Does not seem like a reasonable thing to do.

Here is an updated 5.1 working example.  I stripped it down even more from your linked repo.  But the only thing that I really changed was the token manager.

```
# index.php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App();
$app->run();

final class App
{
    public function run()
    {
        $csrfGenerator = new UriSafeTokenGenerator();
        $csrfStorage = new NativeSessionTokenStorage();
        $csrfManager = new CsrfTokenManager($csrfGenerator, $csrfStorage);

        $twig = new Environment(new FilesystemLoader([
            '../templates',
            '../vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form',
        ]));

        $formEngine = new TwigRendererEngine(['form_div_layout.html.twig'], $twig);

        $twig->addRuntimeLoader(new FactoryRuntimeLoader([
            FormRenderer::class => function () use ($formEngine,$csrfManager) {
                return new FormRenderer($formEngine, $csrfManager);
            },
        ]));
        $twig->addExtension(new TranslationExtension());
        $twig->addExtension(new FormExtension());

        $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
            ->addExtension(new CsrfExtension($csrfManager))
            //->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
            ->getFormFactory();

        $form = $formFactory->createBuilder()
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
            ->getForm();

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $form->submit($_POST[$form->getName()]); // form
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                dump('form is valid');
            }
        }
        echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

The composer.json is simply:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/form": "^5.1",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^5.1",
        "symfony/translation": "^5.1",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "^5.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.1"
    }
}
```

If you still have trouble then I would suggest tracking down where the sessions are stored and then verifying the that csrf token is being properly stored.  It should look something like:

```
_csrf|a:1:{s:4:"form";s:43:"9v1tUNe3J3eYVOmEPwVdz5_iISfzBg8Qa9pLMV8tSN4";}
```

This was actually kind of an interesting exercise in using the twig system for standalone forms. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints you've written! I've just found the issue. Trying to load in a different browser or incognito mode - everything worked as expected in all examples. It turned out my Chrome app contained 3Mb of garbage for localhost address. The issue resolved when I cleared storage in browser application section.  It's my silliest mistake of the year :) Indeed, Form component is the most interesting part of symfony.

Comment: Your code works even with the two different token managers?  Interesting.

Comment: Yeah, on calling `->getToken('form')` they both return the same token value.

Comment: I checked the code.  Creating a new token manager without arguments ends up defaulting to UriSafeTokenGenerator and NativeSessionTokenStorage.  So they both do the same thing.