# How to use Twig path, form, asset, routes without symfony

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, routes, twig, entity-framework-migrations

I have a custom MVC website and I want to move this one to Symfony.

I think that I have to do this in 2 parts : move template to Twig then install Symfony.

Composer is installed and I use Twig and a few bundle of Symfony.

I work actually on moving template to Twig and this one works.

But to earn time, my Twig template have to be perfect because I have to update all pages.

I'm going well but I don't find all responses.

Do you know how to use

- asset `{{ asset('vendor/.css') }}` -> composer require symfony/asset ?
- path and routes `{{ path('page.one') }}`
- use FormType `{{ form_label(form.login)}}`

without symfony ?

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: You will almost certainly be better off installing the framework and then moving your functionality over.  Having said that, by the strangest of coincidences, an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581601/using-symfony-form-component-standalone-with-security-csrf-error-on-submission/63584233#63584233) was just posted which addresses how to render a form using twig in a standalone application.  If you can understand the code then you might have a shot at understanding how to implement the assets and routing functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't move in one time for Symfony. I have to do this step by step by using Twig final code without Symfony :-)

Solution find for the path.

I have created a Twig extension and this one works I think that I can do the same
for asset.

My extension code works like debug extension:

```
<?php

namespace Twig\Extension {
use Twig\TwigFunction;
use App\MyApp\Config;

final class MyAppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions(): array {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('path', 'twig_path', ['is_safe' => $isDumpOutputHtmlSafe ? ['html'] : [], 'needs_context' => true, 'needs_environment' => true, 'is_variadic' => true]),
        ];
    }
}
}

namespace {

    use App\MyApp\Config;
    use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Template;
use Twig\TemplateWrapper;

    function twig_path(Environment $env, $context, ...$vars)
    {
        ob_start();

        $url = [Array_with_my_path];
        echo $url[$vars[0]];
        foreach ($vars[1] as $key => $param_id) {
            echo $param_id;
            break;
        }
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

And in Twig : `{{ path('fichiers.view', {'fichierId' : fichier.fichier_id}) }}` Same like Symfony !!!

And in my controller :

```
$loader = new FilesystemLoader(DOCROOT.'templates/');
    $twig = new Environment($loader,[
        'debug' => true,
        'path' => true
    ]);
    $twig->addExtension(new DebugExtension());
    $twig->addExtension(new MyAppExtension());
    $menu = new Menu($this->controller);
```

The same method works for asset. `{{ asset('assets/vendor/nova-icons/nova-icons.css') }}`

I found a solution for Form in a standalone MVC.

Link for the symfony doc who explain how to do : https://www.bookstack.cn/read/symfony-v4.3/9e14e755983b348b.md

This works.

I have solved my problem.